# Oracle SQL LIKE Query

Tags: sql, oracle

Im new here to StackOverflow and relatively new to IT, just learning the ropes of SQL. Please forgive me if I have posted this in the wrong location or asked a silly question.

Hoping to get some assistance with the following issue I am having:

I have an Oracle database (using Oracle SQL Developer to access it).

I am trying to execute a command and cannot seem to figure out how to extract from the database. I am trying to discover the **number** of departments in column (**DEPTNAME**) that contain the string 'computer' in their title.

I thought the following command would give me my answer, but it is just returning a value of 0:

```
select count(DEPTNAME)
from Department
where DEPTNAME LIKE '%comp%';
```

However when I use this command, I get a return of 41. This number isn't correct however.

```
select count(DEPTNAME)
from Department
where DEPTNAME LIKE '%c%';
```

I essentially just need to know the command for a the DBMS to find a random string and display the amount of times this string appears in the columns.

Comment: Your first command should return the correct result. Are you sure the names contain *computer* and not *Computer* (i.e. uppercase vs. lowercase) ? Please [edit] your question and add sample input (i.e. contents of your department table)

Comment: @FrankSchmitt - not necessarily. Even if case wasn't the issue, checking only for `comp` would also return `competitive programming` and `decompression`. The two solutions offered both make this point.

Comment: add sample data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Oracle, comparisons are case-sensitive by default.  You might want to try:

```
select count(DEPTNAME)
from Department
where lower(DEPTNAME) LIKE '%comp%';
```

Or, better yet:

```
select count(DEPTNAME)
from Department
where lower(DEPTNAME) LIKE '%computer%';
```

Answer (score 0):

try to write 'computer' full name... make sure of the upper and lower cases, and make sure it is written correctly

```
select count(DEPTNAME)  
from Department
where DEPTNAME LIKE '%computer%';
```

else '%c%' will return all the words that contain c in any place in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Thank-you all for your replies. This gave me what I was looking for! It was a case sensitive issue:

```
select count(DEPTNAME)
from Department
where lower(DEPTNAME) LIKE '%comp%';
```

Comment: You should accept the answer that solved your problem (e.g. Gordon's) not add the same answer again.

Comment: Thanks sorry about that